# How to fix the font inside terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Here's my problem. Let me know if anyone knows how to fix it. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an unsuitable font. Let's try setting the Terminal's font back to default:

`gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings font ''`

Restart Terminal to verify. Terminal is supposed to use a Monospace variety, any other font type will look abnormal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this didn't help.